# Need to parse repeatedly (loop) over the same piece of XML using NSXMLParser

Tags: objective-c, xml, ios9, nsxmlparser

I have a string of XML that I'd like to use to describe a table layout. Sort of like a template. I'm using NSXMLParser to parse this.

```
<section title="section a">
    <row label="name" property="fullname" />
    <row label="gender" property="gender" />
</section>
<section title="section b">
    <row label="pet" property="pet" />
</section>
<repeat foreach="companies">
    <section title="name">
        <row label="address" property="address" />
        <row label="email" property="email" />
    </section>
</repeat>
```

As for the part between the `<repeat>` tags, I intent to loop over this part 0 to n times for each of the entries in an array. The NSXMLParser however doesn't seem to have an easy way of doing this. I see no option to jump back to a previous line. The only way I can think of is storing everything between the `<repeat>` tags in a variable and doing my custom parsing and repeating of it in the parser:didEndElement:... method. I wonder though, isn't there a better way to do this maybe?

Comment: Why would you need to reparse the XML over and over? Just parse it once. Store the resulting data as needed. Then reuse that data over and over as needed.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy. Maybe i'm overthinking this, but I have a lot of logic going on when building the arrays while parsing. Are you saying I should parse this all into multidimensional arrays/dictionaries first and then loop over that again to apply the logic to create more arrays/dictionaries which I can then use as source data for my table?